# Mockingoose _id: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined error

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mongoose, mockingoose

I have a simple express routine to save incoming data:

```js
app.post('/news', async (req, res, next) => {
  const news = await model.create(req.body);
  res.status(201).json(news);
});
```

And I want to write unit test for this by using `mockingoose` and `supertest`.

```js
it('should create news', async () => {
  mockingoose(NesModel).toReturn({ _id: '507f191e810c19729de860ea', title: 'dadsd' }, 'save');

  const res = await request(app)
    .post('/news')
    .send({
      title: 'ABC',
      content: 'adbasdasdsad'
    });

  expect(res.statusCode).toBe(201);
});
```

And I get this error:

```
  ● News › should create news

    ValidationError: News validation failed: _id: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined

      at new ValidationError (node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:31:11)
      at model.Document.invalidate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2563:32)
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2385:17
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1181:9
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix this. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've got a very similar problem but not using mockingoose at all. Simply with Mongoose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't give full code example here because of trying to keep question simple. But it turned out this problem doesn't occur with a situation that simple. And I realised that problem occurs about some external plugins(`mongoose-slug-hero` here) because they are using more methods of Mongoose models that mockingoose doesn't provide. Problem can be different on all different plugins. Also `populate` doesn't work properly with mockingoose too. You need to do [some more workaround](https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose/issues/48) for fixing it.

At the end I run away from mockingoose and started using [jest-mongodb](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb#readme) involuntarily(Because I think this is anti pattern for unit-tests).